# Safari debugger and console log history

Tags: debugging, ios-simulator, ionic2

I'm trying to debug an Ionic 2 mobile application on simulator. My problem is that I need to get the console logs from the beginning (not just only from when I open the debugger), because I run some code when the app starts and I'm unable to see if this is correct. 
On chrome and android I got all the history in the console (even if I open it later). How can I get the same from my iPhone Simulator ?

I also tried with `ionic emulate -l -c ios`
but my app stops at the splash screen :/

Thanks !

Comment: Why you don't use XCODE and the console plugin? If you run your app, the messages are shown up inside a windows of XCODE.

Comment: yes but I always forget to build with ionic before, so it's annoying :)